# Django error: name 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL' is not defined

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-errors

I am trying to take advantage of the global variable `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in the **settings.py** file in my Django project to avoid duplicating URLs everywhere.

In my **settings.py** I have redefined `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` like so:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "my_app_name:index"
```

I am trying to use `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in my `login_view` in **views.py** as follows:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
    else: ...
```

However, when I log in I get the following error message:

> name 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL' is not defined

I thought about importing `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` from **settings.py** but that feels wrong since other variables from there do not need to be imported anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the settings to use *settings variables*

```
from django.conf import settings

...

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import settings in order to use LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL